# Can't use a mounted folder on Linux without root

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10, file-sharing

I used the command `mount -t cifs //<server>/<source> /<dest> -o user=<user>` to mount a folder onto `~/Desktop/Server`, but I can only write with sudo. I can read fine.

The Windows sharing settings on my folder should be allowing for it to work, since the user the the `mount` command is logging in has access. I even tried giving "everyone" access, and it still didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably mounted it as `root` so I am assuming that the permission of the mountpoint are `root:root`. Use `ls -alF` to verify. Use root to give yourself permission to access the dir. `chown \`whoami\`:\`whoami\` /path/to/mountpoint`

Comment: Hey, this looks useful, but I found it hard to understand. If it's not too much to ask, can you put this into an answer with each command, step-by-step? In the meantime I'll see If I can figure out the commands

Comment: OK, `ls -alF` reports that you are correct. If my Windows username is WinUser, and my Linux username is LinUser, what should the command be?

Comment: I tried `chown root:root`, `root:LinUser`, `LinUser:root`, and `LinUser:LinUser`. Each time, `ls -alF` reports no change...

Comment: @Matt Clark doing `cd <folder location>` and then `chown <myname> file` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option **`-o UserName`** you gave to mount tells the Windows machine which Windows account is using the share. It is completely unrelated to the Linux username doing the mount.

A Linux user is only allowed to mount devices which are listed in **`/etc/fstab`** with the **`user`** flag. So, just add the following line to your **`/etc/fstab`**:

```
//<server>/<source> /media/<dest> cifs user=<user>,noauto,users 0 0
```

Then mount as user (without sudo) by running **`mount /media/<dest>`**. This should work fine.

Comment: mount -o uid=86 /dev/windoze /ementee/winz

Comment: Wait, why do I have to specify the locations in `/etc/fstb` and when mounting?

Comment: Also, when editing `/etc/fstb`, should `<user>` by the LinUser or WinUser?

Comment: Ah, a bit of testing, and it worked! Thank you so much :D